Unable to screw into the wall right below the ceiling
Our home was built in 2006 in Wisconsin (location is listed because I know building materials can change by climate). It seems that there’s something behind the drywall where the wall meets the vaulted ceiling. I use a stud finder but I cannot penetrate past the drywall. What would the builder have used to transition from wall to vaulted ceiling? I’m trying to hang curtains from the very highest point (10’) on the wall (floor to ceiling curtains) with no luck.

Might be steel connectors between the wall/roof joint, or a steel beam.  Steel protection plates for electric/plumbing lines is less likely but need possible.

I use a stud finder but I cannot penetrate past the drywall ... what does that mean? ... what does the stud finder indicate?

The screw goes into the wall but only through the drywall, it won’t penetrate whatever is behind the drywall. The stud finder indicates a stud.
